# Moose method modifiers in base class don't get called

Tags: perl, oop, moose, method-modifier

It's cool that it's possible to add them in sub classes or mix them in in roles. My problem is that it seems method modifiers from the base class get deactivated when subclasses redefine the method itself (not the modifier). Maybe I'm understanding method modifiers wrong. Example:

```
use feature 'say';

package Foo;
use Moose;

has called => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Bool', default => 0);
sub call { 'Foo called' }
after call => sub { shift->called(1) };

my  $foo = Foo->new();
say $foo->called;   # 0
say $foo->call;     # Foo called
say $foo->called;   # 1

package Bar;
use Moose;
extends 'Foo';

sub call { 'Bar called' }

my  $bar = Bar->new();
say $bar->called;   # 0
say $bar->call;     # Bar called
say $bar->called;   # 0
```

I expected the last output to be `1` like with `$foo`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965197/in-perl-moose-how-can-i-apply-a-modifier-to-a-method-in-all-subclasses

Comment: Thanks, @RobEarl, will definitely have a look! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is this

- you define a Foo::call
- you modify that with after
- you define a Bar::call that doesn't call Foo::Call

The modifiers are not magical runtime things, but class-definition time things. To do what you try to do here you'd have to structure your code differently

Comment: Thanks, Leon! Do you have an idea how to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

@RobEarl posted a link to a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4965197/1184510). The solution posted over there was to use [`augment`](http://p3rl.org/Moose::Cookbook::Basics::Document_AugmentAndInner) and although it looks a bit strange and its use is controversial, it could solve my problem:

```
package Foo;
use Moose;

has called => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Bool', default => 0);
sub call { inner(); shift->called(1); 'Foo called' }

package Bar;
use Moose;
extends 'Foo';

augment call => sub { 'Bar called' };

my  $bar = Bar->new();
say $bar->called;   # 0
say $bar->call;     # Bar called
say $bar->called;   # 1
```